# What is the format of the static libraries shipping with legacy Microsoft C for DOS?

Tags: ms-dos, c, file-format, microsoft

I have installed Microsoft C 5.10 on DOS 6.22. It created a 'LIB' directory with static libraries to link against. Now I need to extract the symbols and the code for the functions from them, but can't find the format documented anywhere:

```
ninja@desktop:/mnt/d/backup/dos/msc510-install/LIB$ ls *.LIB
CLIBC7.LIB  CLIBCE.LIB  GRAPHICS.LIB  LLIBC7.LIB  LLIBCE.LIB  MLIBC7.LIB  MLIBCE.LIB  SLIBC7.LIB  SLIBCE.LIB
ninja@desktop:/mnt/d/backup/dos/msc510-install/LIB$ file CLIBC7.LIB
CLIBC7.LIB: Microsoft Visual C library
```

Supposedly, static libraries from more recent versions of (Visual) C are COFF archives which can be expanded with ar, but it does not seem to work for these legacy libraries.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are OMF libraries; you can analyse them with Agner Fog’s [object file converter](https://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv).

It probably only makes sense to work with those libraries if you intend to build software with Microsoft C 5.1, in which case you’d use the tools provided with the compiler (`LIB.EXE` in particular).

The OMF format is described in detail in [OMF: Relocatable Object Module Format](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/Omfg.pdf).

Comment: yep OMF was and still is the standard ...

Comment: thanks, I'm trying to reverse engineer some old software built with that compiler, finding the library function signatures will make my life much easier.

Comment: The GNU binutil's "objcopy" and "objdump" utilities could well be your friends here ... they can convert to and from many object file formats, including OMF.